# Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31) driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, atheros

I'm trying to get WiFi to work (device: `Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)`) and I found the following line in the `dmesg` output.

```
Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
```

Now, I guess this driver is not included in my kernel (`Linux 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux; Ubuntu Linux 16.04`), so I have to clone [The `ath10k` GitHub repo](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git).

Which files do I have to copy to which directories i.o. to install the driver?

**EDIT**

After downloading the firmware package, installing it and rebooting the device is still not working.

When I try to connect I just get (in the `dmesg` output):

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

The command `dmesg | grep ath` gives me

```
[    3.497692] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.743026] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    6.290044] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 (0x05020001, 0x003821ff sub 11ad:08a6) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[    6.290049] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    6.291556] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[    6.291559] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    6.291562] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    6.291563] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[    6.298835] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite often, the driver looks for one of several firmware files. Failing to find the first, it prints the 'failed' message, looks for the second (or third), finds it and loads the firmware.

I suggest that you update the firmware as follows; with a working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.163_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and tell us if your wireless is working. If you are still having issues, please show us:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

NOTE: Edited to update the link that changes very often.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken

Comment: @torkleyy the correct link is `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.163_all.deb` or `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/‌​linux-firmware_1.79.‌​18_all.deb`

Comment: @heynnema thanks. I've updated my answer; it didn't change anything

Comment: @torkleyy I changed my comment slightly. You might try again. Uninstall the current one first.

Comment: @torkleyy you might also edit `/etc/default/crda` and set `REGDOMAIN=US` changing `US` to the correct country code. Reboot after.

Comment: @heynnema I've tried that; I'm now getting a kernel panic :( but I had this panic before (after installing the system) but it disappeared...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53692/discussion-between-torkleyy-and-heynnema).