# Ideapad 310-15ISK wifi not working

Tags: wireless, atheros, ideapad

I have a notebook Lenovo Ideapad 310-15ISK and sometimes the wireless works, sometimes it doesn't.

When I turn on the notebook and the wireless works, it keep working still I turn of or reboot the notebook. When I turn on the notebook and the wireless is not working, I have to reboot or turn it on again still it works.

Note: my NB doesn`t have a physical wireless/wifi switch or a shrtcut on the keyboard. The F7 button is the airplane mode.

**What I can do to fix it?**

```
Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 80UH
    Version: Lenovo ideapad 310-15ISK
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_80UH_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad 310-15ISK
    Family: IDEAPAD
```

with the command lspci I got:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 30)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)


Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

[image]

==============================================================================

Hi AlexOnLinux. Thank you very much for your help. As asked, folow the **wireless-info-script output**:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 Jun 2018 20:50 -05 -0500

Booted last: 13 Jun 2018 00:00 -05 -0500

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.16.12-041612-generic #201805251538 SMP Fri May 25 15:40:25 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3854]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:4035]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e360 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:2408 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
ath10k_pci             49152  0
ath10k_core           372736  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    28672  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              778240  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              626688  3 mac80211,ath,ath10k_core
wmi                    24576  3 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp1s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet xxxxxxxxx  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast xxxxxxxxx
        inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0
        inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0
        inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0
        inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether   txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 44957  bytes 32175553 (32.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 37179  bytes 7428831 (7.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 14148  bytes 1168160 (1.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14148  bytes 1168160 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
        ether   txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27708  bytes 28742741 (28.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15993  bytes 3134500 (3.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0                         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp1s0
0.0.0.0                         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0
                0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp1s0
                0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp1s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root       875     1  0 Jun08 ?        00:00:13 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp1s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Conexão cabeada 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       5dba2d2e-cdfa-3cb2-864e-50bffdcb4d1a
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = , mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = , nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = , nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = xxxxxxxxxxx, mt = 0
IP4.DNS[1]:                             
IP4.DNS[2]:                             
IP4.DNS[3]:                             
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        default_ip_ttl = 64
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       time_offset = 0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       routers = 
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       expiry = 1528944458
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_host_name = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         
IP6.ADDRESS[4]:                         
IP6.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 
IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = 
IP6.ROUTE[6]:                           dst = 
IP6.ROUTE[7]:                           dst = 
IP6.DNS[1]:                             
IP6.DNS[2]:                             
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = 
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        rebind = 54000
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        max_life = 86400
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        preferred_life = 72000
DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[8]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[9]:                        life_starts = 1528940864
DHCP6.OPTION[10]:                       ip6_address = 
DHCP6.OPTION[11]:                       ip6_prefixlen = 
DHCP6.OPTION[12]:                       renew = 36000
DHCP6.OPTION[13]:                       starts = 1528940864
DHCP6.OPTION[14]:                       iaid = 
DHCP6.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp6_server_id = 0:3:0:1:
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{4}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   5dba2d2e-cdfa-3cb2-864e-50bffdcb4d1a | Conexão cabeada 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath10k_pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.16.12-041612-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=false

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Goiabinha]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Goiabinha | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Goiabinha
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/techseg escritorio]] (600 root)
[connection] id=techseg escritorio | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=techseg escritorio
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Patricia]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Patricia | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Patricia
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Rio_Branco (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp1s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Patricia"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000007becfc797
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4848ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"#NET-CLARO-WIFI"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000007becfd05b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4848ms ago
          Cell 03 - Address: 
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Goiabinha"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000013fc6263fd
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4544ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: 
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Goiabinha_linda"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000e1b86fd943
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4600ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[ath10k_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.12-041612-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac WLAN PCIe/AHB devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     228292A42E3072B9E09755C
depends:        ath10k_core
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_pci
vermagic:       4.16.12-041612-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)

[ath10k_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.12-041612-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac wireless LAN cards.
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     CC082A2E2C2D3E1AF7B1E63
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_core
vermagic:       4.16.12-041612-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           uart_print:Uart target debugging (bool)
parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for calibration in testmode (bool)
parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)
parm:           rawmode:Use raw 802.11 frame datapath (bool)
parm:           coredump_mask:Bitfield of what to include in firmware crash file (ulong)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.12-041612-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     555BBBB9D4FCA58A05E7C0D
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath
vermagic:       4.16.12-041612-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.12-041612-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     8FA1436C1506A22E399CDBE
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.16.12-041612-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.12-041612-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     7CDD5816888A499C5A9E803
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.16.12-041612-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath10k_pci]
irq_mode: 0
reset_mode: 0

[ath10k_core]
coredump_mask: 3
cryptmode: 0
debug_mask: 0
rawmode: N
skip_otp: N
uart_print: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist ideapad_laptop

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[21907.682946] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x300 build 0x3e8, firmware rome 0x300 build 0x111
[21908.256612] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 4 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Sorry, i can only give you some hints: Perhaps it is a driver problem: Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/994555/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-31-wi-fi-driver-installation and https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation and https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware - Maybe an easy solution could be to switch to ubuntu 16.04. When you do not have any wifi connection, what is the output of `lspci -knn` compared to when the connection is established?

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas. I'll try to do that according to the links above. The last times that I rebooted the NB the wifi always worked, so I don't know if it was fixed by an update or not. So when(if) it doesn't work again I post here  the output of lspci -knn compared.  I had ubuntu 16.04 but the problema was the same. I just switched do ubuntu 17.10 to try an earlier kernel. Thanks again.       Fernando

Comment: UBUNTU 18.04 Now, follow lspci -knn with wifi not working:  

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3854] Kernel driver in use: r8169
 Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 30)
 Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:4035]
 Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

Comment: I followed the instructions bellow and the problem continues. Someone can help me? Another way? I upgraded to the Ubuntu 18.04 and the problem continues. Thanks

Comment: Hello, could you please edit your question and add the information u get, when executing the wireless-info-script https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info - That script list a lot of usefull information about network-hardware and makes it easier for troubleshooting https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/669014

Comment: Hi AlexOnLinux. Thank you very much for your help. As asked, folow the wireless-info-script output on https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wMY9YZ9NkG/        also in the question above.

Comment: Hey Fernando, i just checked your wifi-script-output and don't see any problem. I guess your wifi-card was working properly when you did run the script. Could you rerun the script again, when your wifi is not working, so we can compare the outputs?