# Help 6Mb/s WIFI connection speed Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, atheros

I am fairly new to Ubuntu. I have installed 16.04LTS on a new Dell Inspiron 5565. Everything seemed to be working fine until I noticed I had a slow Internet connection. When I look at my "Connection Information" it is showing the Speed at 6Mb/s. On my windows partition, I get 400+ Mb/s. I have tried the following:

[Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation)

sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

[Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994555/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-31-wi-fi-driver-installation)

Nothing has seemed to work thus far. 
Here is what I am working with:

cat proc/version

> Linux version 4.13.0-26-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-031) (gcc version
>   5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5)) #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018

lspci -vvnn |grep -A 9 Network

> Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev
>   31)   Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:1810]  Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+
>   SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B-
>   DisINTx+  Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast
>
> > TAbort- SERR-    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci    Kernel modules:
> >     ath10k_pci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My connection information also shows 6 Mbps:

```
$ iwconfig
enp59s0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp60s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TELUS1213-5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 70:F1:96:42:5F:06   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=17 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:81   Missed beacon:0
```

However speedtest.net reports almost 60 Mbps throughput:

[image: internet speed wifi]

Running the same test on an Ethernet adapter rated at 1000 Mbps results in same 60 Mbps Internet download speed. So speed is limited by ISP not by WiFi. Relevant `lspci -vv`:

```
3b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Device 0707:2400
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at dd600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx

3c:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 137
    Region 0: Memory at dd200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

I can't explain why the `iwconfig` speed is so low when the real speed is so high. The same results are obtained from other Linux CLI sources:

```
$ iw dev wlp60s0 link
    (... SNIP ...)
    freq: 5220
    RX: 1421503515 bytes (4545343 packets)
    TX: 131449836 bytes (1061284 packets)
    signal: -55 dBm
    tx bitrate: 6.0 MBit/s

    bss flags:  short-preamble short-slot-time
    dtim period:    2
    beacon int: 100

$ iwlist wlp60s0 bitrate
wlp60s0   unknown bit-rate information.
          Current Bit Rate=6 Mb/s
```

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix, that is exactly my issue. I do not know why I did not think to do a speed test and just trusted the connection information. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, my iwconfig shows 144.4 Mb/s. My speedtest shows 303.69 Mbit/s. I think that the number in iwconfig means nothing.