# Conky option/wariable wireless_bitrate

Tags: wireless, ethernet, conky

I have enabled option

```
# Line from my config
${color grey}Rate:$color ${wireless_bitrate wlp1s0}
```

in my config.
But i noticed that it is not updating properly.
Here is screenshot from NetworManager
[image: Networ Manager screenshot]

Here is conky screenschot
[image]

It seems that conky checks download bitrate only an connection and does not update this value.

How can i enable update of this value?
Also question: wich option shows ethernet connection Rate(speed)?

**UPD**

From comment @WinEunuuchs2Unix
Command `iwlist` shows all time one fixed speed.
Here is example with `watch`

```
Every 1,0s: iwlist wlp1s0 bitrate                       Sun Apr  8 18:58:12 2018

wlp1s0    unknown bit-rate information.
      Current Bit Rate=144,4 Mb/s
```

But NetworkManager show that speed is changing.
Screenshot in front of router:
[image]

Screenshot in other room:
[image]

Comment: Can you post your section of conky code that displays `Rate: 144.4 Mb/s`?

Comment: I edited my post with line from my config.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If you use `iwlist wlp1s0 bitrate` does the bit rate display correctly?

Comment: I made one more update

Comment: Thanks for the second update. The last thing to do is run a real speed test to see which of the two is correct. I use Oakla speed test: http://www.speedtest.net/

Comment: My internet is slower than my wifi %) But i tested this speeds with my  NAS in network. Proper speed are displayed via NetworkManager and not via conky.

Comment: I spent 1/2 hour researching various linux commands to reveal wifi bitrate and they are all coming up wrong: `iw dev wlp60s0 link`, `iwconfig wlp60s0` and `iwlist wlp60s0 bitrate`. Conky probably uses one of these sources. The best **Ask Ubuntu** answer I can find as to discrepancy is actually one I wrote in January: https://askubuntu.com/questions/998557/help-6mb-s-wifi-connection-speed-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-31/998636#998636

Answer (score 1):

May we call this an educated speculation rather than an answer?

I strongly feel that this, gathered from `iwconfig` as well as Network Manager, tells us what the wireless router and the wireless card have negotiated:

> Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s

I think that means, that the router will communicate at, in my case, 866.7 Mb/s with several big caveats:

• Does your ISP provide service at 866.7 Mb/s or greater?

• Does the website you’ve contacted transmit data at 866.7 Mb/s or greater? This is doubtful, except for some speedtest sites.

• Are other devices on the same network busy using the wireless at the same time you need it? Is Dropbox running? Is an iPad backing up in the upstairs bedroom?

• Is there any interference from microwave ovens, cordless phones, near power lines in a wall, or near a breaker box?

• Are we on a non-overlapping channel?

In practice, we will almost never achieve the maximum negotiated speed.

In the case of conky, I feel that the screenshot you posted reflects what is actually happening at the moment the screenshot was taken. Network Manager reflects what is theoretically possible in shielded, laboratory conditions.

Comment: +1 but I still feel there are "glitches" in the Linux methodology of discovering **true** bit-rates for WiFi. You commented as much on my answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/998557/help-6mb-s-wifi-connection-speed-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-31/998636#998636 *FWIW, my iwconfig shows 144.4 Mb/s. My speedtest shows 303.69 Mbit/s. I think that the number in iwconfig means nothing.* - **chili555 Jan 22 at 14:11** I guess my point is `conky` is getting data from `iwconfig` or some similar Linux source.