# Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31) ubuntu 14.04 wifi not detected

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros

i followed this [Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994555/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-31-wi-fi-driver-installation) and it last line brings an error. i solved the problem before but i had to remove ubuntu and reinstall it again and now i don't know how to get it working again

Comment: http://termbin.com/074j                                                                                                  this is the url when i run "dmesg | grep ath | nc termbin.com 9999"

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are different due to some changes at github, in terminal

```
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo cp WLAN.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 firmware-5.bin
```

Reboot