# Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31) Network unclaimed

Tags: networking, drivers

I am having trouble getting my wifi adapter working ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have followed the instructions at the following link, and have tried multiple files contained within the firmware section with no success. I succeeded in getting my ethrenet controller working by installing the correct drivers, however, I have woefully failed to get my wifi adapter to work. I have spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to solve this issue. Please help.

[Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31) driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883651/qualcomm-atheros-device-0042-rev-31-driver)

Here is some information on my current system.

Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-1025-gcp
Architecture: x86-64

sudo lshw -c network

*-network UNCLAIMED

```
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 31
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:e0200000-e03fffff
```

*-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 10
   serial: c6:f0:6d:a4:0b:ce
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.03-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.56 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:43 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:e0904000-e0904fff memory:e0900000-e0903fff
```

---

```
:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus A
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c5)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
04:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 61)
```

```
:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               487424  2 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
nls_iso8859_1          16384  2
kvm_amd                98304  0
ccp                    86016  1 kvm_amd
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_amd
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              20480  0
video                  49152  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
drm                   491520  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_generic            16384  0
uas                    28672  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   131072  2 usbhid,hid_generic
usb_storage            77824  2 uas
ahci                   40960  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
r8168                 548864  0
```

Comment: The link provided should actually rout to this url: https://askubuntu.com/questions/994555/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-31-wi-fi-driver-installation

Comment: Interestingly, I booted into the grub menu, advanced options, and set my Kernal to a previous version. All my driver issues that I have been having are now fixed. Wifi, Audio, BlueTooth. If anyone has any insight into this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try using this command:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```